# Surround Variable with Single Quotes when Passing SQL Smalldatetime

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem/question that I may have been staring at too long today.

I have a stored procedure that receives data from an web application.  The data comes in as smalldate time format.  I am trying to pass this information to a second stored procedure but the second one won't fire unless the data is in single quotes.  Would it be better to cast this as varchar?

The SET @CompletedDate must be '2010-01-20 15:28:00" for obvious reasons.  How do I pass this information to the second procedure?

```
DECLARE @return_value int
    ,@TaskID int
    ,@CompletedDate smalldatetime
SET @TaskID = 90
SET @CompletedDate = 2010-01-20 15:28:00

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Task_Completion]
        @TaskID = @TaskID,
        @CompletedDate = @CompletedDate
```

Here is the usp_Task_Completion SP

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_Task_Completion]
@TaskID int 
,@CompletedDate smalldatetime
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

--Mark Transaction as complete
UPDATE dbo.Task
SET Completed = 1
    ,CompletedDate =  @CompletedDate
WHERE TaskID = @TaskID
```

Comment: how does usp_Task_Completion define the @CompletedDate parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

no because a varchar will also have to be enclosed in single quotes, just put quotes around it

```
DECLARE @return_value int
    ,@TaskID int
    ,@CompletedDate smalldatetime
SET @TaskID = 90
SET @CompletedDate = '2010-01-20 15:28:00'

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Task_Completion]
        @TaskID = @TaskID,
        @CompletedDate = @CompletedDate
```

Comment: That is what I was thinking too I just can't get it to pass the smalldatetime through.

Comment: That is where I am having issues.  It doesn't error I just won't run the usp_Task_Completion_SP which is a simple UPDATE SET command

Comment: what happens when you run the proc exactly as I have in the code snippet?

Comment: I just added the usp_Task_Completion to the original question.

Comment: The TaskID is actually also being passed from the application.  But let that prompted a question to ask my developer...  You may be on to something with this

Comment: @SQLMenace It looks like the application was not passing the @TaskID variable.  In my testing I was just setting it to a real value. Looks like I have been chasing my tail on this one.

Comment: What I should have done was fired up SQL Profiler and watched the transaction to find this before I posted anything...  Live and learn but it goes as a lesson.  Use the tools you have.  Thank you to everyone for responding.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you have to enclose that small datetime 2010-01-20 15:28:00 into single quotes -> '2010-01-20 15:28:00'

Comment: I know that I am trying to figure out how I can pass the variable enclosed in single quotes like ''' + @CompletedDate + '''

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a naming confict on @CompletedDate. Change the variable name in the declare, and then change your set command to use single quotes, like this:

```
SET @CompletedDateNewName = '2010-01-20 15:28:00'
```

@CompletedDate can still be a smalldatetime type

Comment: that is not a problem..see here

create proc prTest 
@id int as
select @id as id
go

declare @id int
set @id = 5
exec prTest @id = @id
go

Comment: Yeah I have confirmed that the naming convention is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little much for a comment.  What's the problem?  Below are my tests:

```
/*
create proc usp_Task_Completion (
    @TaskID int,
    @CompletedDate smalldatetime)
as 

    return 1000
*/
go


DECLARE @return_value int
    ,@TaskID int
    ,@CompletedDate smalldatetime
SET @TaskID = 90

/* This works */
--SET @CompletedDate = '2010-01-20 15:28:00'    

/* This doesn't work (incorrect syntax near '15'. */
--SET @CompletedDate = 2010-01-20 15:28:00      

/* This runs but yields unintended results (2010-01-20 = 1989; convert to datetime = '1905-06-13' */
SET @CompletedDate = 2010-01-20 

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[usp_Task_Completion]
        @TaskID = @TaskID,
        @CompletedDate = @CompletedDate

select @return_value
```

Comment: the one that works doesn't because you get integer arithmetic

run this
declare @CompletedDate smalldatetime

SET @CompletedDate = 2010-01-20 

select @CompletedDate

-- output 1905-06-13 00:00:00

Comment: @SQLMenace -- true.  I will amend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the CompletedDate column isn't smalldatetime, and it's trying to cast every value in that column into the smalldatetime type (with some failing). Please check the column type to be really sure.

Comment: Nope we are good there.  It looks like I have been racking my brain for nothing and was a bug that the application was not passing the @TaskID variable.

Comment: Incidentally - just because the web app is giving you a smalldatetime type, doesn't mean the database wants that. If the column is actually datetime, or maybe even char(19), you should cast your variable before comparing it.

Comment: you are correct that the app and database need to sync up but it looks like this issue is the @TaskID variable not being set by the application.